# Query for self join in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query which gets the correct result but it is taking 5.5 sec to get the output.. Is there any other way to write a query for this -

```
SELECT metricName, metricValue 
FROM Table sm  
WHERE createdtime = (
    SELECT MAX(createdtime) 
    FROM Table b 
    WHERE sm.metricName = b.metricName 
    AND b.sinkName='xx' 
) 
AND sm.sinkName='xx'
```

Comment: Provide `EXPLAIN` + all tables schemas

Comment: Maybe rewrite subquery to join? http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/429-how-to-convert-subqueries-to-joins/ or https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rewriting-subqueries.html

Comment: `createdtime` should be an index in `b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, the subselect has to be run for every result row of the outer query, which should be quite expensive. Instead, you could select your filter data in a separate query and join both accordingly:

```
SELECT `metricName`, `metricValue` FROM Table sm 
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(`createdtime`) AS `maxTime, `metricName` from Table b WHERE b.sinkName='xx' GROUP BY `metricName` ) filter
  ON (sm.`createdtime` = filter.`maxTime`) AND ( sm.`metricName` = filter.`metricName`)
WHERE sm.sinkName='xx'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked like a charm.. It took just 0.013s.. Thank you